# HSSF. How do I concat every single column in string?

Tags: java, apache-poi, hssf

My data is stored in a format(look down): [-] means a blank cell,
    on the right may be only 10 columns, after the space. Something like this:

```
        [string0] [-] [string1] [string2] [string3] .. [string10] [-]
```

How to change this code for:

1. obtain full string, for EACH row fullString = [-] [string1] [string2] [string3] .. [string10] [-]. StringBuilder? Or how?

   ```
   //Get first sheet from the workbook
   HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

   //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
   Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
   while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
       Row row = rowIterator.next();

       //For each row, iterate through each columns
       Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
       while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

           Cell cell = cellIterator.next();    
           switch(cell.getCellType()) {
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                   System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                   list1.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                   break;
           }
       }
       System.out.println("");
   }
   file.close();
   FileOutputStream out =
           new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\student3\\"+sfilename+".xls");
   workbook.write(out);
   out.close();
   ```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18082358/624003. @Elder, if you are not satisfied with the answer, please put some comments, but not raise a different thread for the same question.

Comment: Please do not post duplicates; and especially do not create new accounts to post duplicates if you have been question-banned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**External Link**: [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

Here is an example that should work.

Maven Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class StackOverflowQuestion18095443 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Please specify the file name as a parameter");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        String sfilename = args[0];
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\student3\\" + sfilename + ".xls");
        read(file);
    }

    public static void read(File file) {
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            HSSFDataFormatter formatter = new HSSFDataFormatter();
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(in);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                StringBuilder rowText = new StringBuilder();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    String cellAsStringValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                    rowText.append(cellAsStringValue).append(" ");
                }
                System.out.println(rowText.toString().trim());
            }
        } catch (InvalidFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```